# Controling line length d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using the following code to produce a circle surrounded by other circles, which are all connected to the main one via `<line>` element. I'm trying to make them unevenly spaced from the circle, but whatever I attempt, I get some sort of chaos. The code is below:

```
var width = 500,
    height = 500;
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(-400)
    .linkDistance(190)
    .on("tick", tick);
var drag = force.drag()
    .on("dragstart", dragstart);
var svg = d3.select("#orb").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("class", "mainsvg");
var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");


d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  link = link.data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");



  node = node.data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("a")      
      .attr("href", "3");

    node.append("g")
      .attr("class", "node");



    node.append("circle")
      .attr("class", "circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return d.color })
      .attr("stroke", function(d){ return d.color })
      .on("dblclick", dblclick);

    node.append("text")
      .attr("class", "text")
      .attr("fill", "white")
      .attr("stroke", "none")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .text( function (d) { return d.name; });


});

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  svg.selectAll(".circle").attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  svg.selectAll(".text").attr("x", function(d) { return d.x+d.xoffs; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y+d.yoffs; });
}
```

Ive tried controlling the x1/y1 and x2/y2 of the `<line>` element but if I move the line, the circle stays the same. Would there be a way to say, cancel equal link distance and set it for each circle individually?

Comment: I tried fixing the nodes via `fixed = true` and manipulating them via x/y but then I lose the small tick animation, they just appear and never move.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve what you want. But the most important thing is remembering that `linkDistance` accepts a function.

For instance, in this snippet, I'm setting the distance in the data array for the links:

```
var links = [{
    source: 1,
    target: 0,
    distance: 50
}, {
    source: 2,
    target: 0,
    distance: 20
}, {
    source: 3,
    target: 0,
    distance: 150
}, {
    source: 4,
    target: 0,
    distance: 80
}, {
    source: 5,
    target: 0,
    distance: 40
}]
```

And using it in the force:

```
.linkDistance(d=>d.distance)
```

Check the snippet:

```js
var nodes = [{
        name: "a"
    }, {
        name: "b"
    }, {
        name: "c"
    }, {
        name: "d"
    }, {
        name: "e"
    }, {
        name: "f"
    }];

    var links = [{
        source: 1,
        target: 0,
        distance: 50
    }, {
        source: 2,
        target: 0,
        distance: 20
    }, {
        source: 3,
        target: 0,
        distance: 150
    }, {
        source: 4,
        target: 0,
        distance: 80
    }, {
        source: 5,
        target: 0,
        distance: 40
    }]

    var width = 400
    height = 300;

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(nodes)
        .links(links)
        .size([width, height])
        .linkDistance(d => d.distance)
        .charge(-1000)
        .on("tick", tick)
        .start();

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(force.links())
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("class", "link");

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(force.nodes())
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .call(force.drag);

    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", (d,i) => i ? 10 : 16)
        .style("fill", (d,i) => i ? "teal" : "brown");

    function tick() {
        link.attr("x1", function(d) {
                return d.source.x;
            })
            .attr("y1", function(d) {
                return d.source.y;
            })
            .attr("x2", function(d) {
                return d.target.x;
            })
            .attr("y2", function(d) {
                return d.target.y;
            });

        node.attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: that literally does exactly what it's supposed to. Now just to figure out how to make it float around less and I'm done. Anytime, every beer you can think of, is on me man, thank you!

Comment: You can play with other parameters... Also, you can render the circles *after* all math is done: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667139

Comment: Technically, I'm fine with them "shimmy-ing" a bit, just not moving the positions, since there are some I want above root node, some below etc. If a top-intended circle floats all the way the left, that's bad. But the small shake is actually deriable